# limit using finite expansion

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find this limit using finite expansion method :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cosh(x))}{x\ln(1+x)}$$

---

So $\cosh(x) = 1+ \frac{x}{2}$
And $\ln{\cosh(x)} = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{24}$
And at last the whole expression would be like this:
 $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}$$
so this would be infinity while verifying this on my calculator gives the answer .5 whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$cosh(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}$$
therefore your limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^2}$$
which is $0.5$

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't notice it.